# How change text of text node in animation node at different frame?

Tags: animation, scripting, text-object, animation-nodes

I have a list of texts of different length.
I have an animation node tree and i have succeeded at showing my text list iteratively at a constant rate (example each 120 frames) in text object output node.
My problem is the constant rate because my texts are of different length.
I would like to show in the text object output each text in the text list but with a different duration (example : text[0] = 120 frames, text[1] = 258 frames, text[2] = 76 frames).
I am wondering if this is achievable with animation node tree.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do it -

- the manual way is to add an Integer List node and type in the length or offset you want to use for each string. The advantage is you can adjust the timing to taste for each string.

[image: intiger list]

- The automatic way is to use a Text Length node to use the length of the string to calculate the offset.

[image: text length node]